# C - getting WIFEXITED to return false for debuging purposes

Tags: c, unix, process, operating-system, wait

I have a simple program that use fork() to create a child process, the child process use execvp() function to execute a Unix method like: "ls" or "echo".
while the child is working the parent process is waiting using the wait() function.
After the child is done the parent check what cause the child to end, using the WIFEXITED() macro. If the child ended not normally the parent print a message on the screen.
For debuging purposes I want to make the child terminate **not** normally, I have tried to run a program that divid by zero but still the line:

```
if(!WIFEXITED(status))
```

return true every time.

My code:

```
int main(){

pid_t p;
int status;
p = fork();
if (p == 0){//child process
    execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    exit(0);        
}else{
    wait(&status);
    if (!WIFEXITED(status))//if the child process terminated not normally
        fprintf(stderr, "\tError Occured!\n");//display error message 
}
return 0;}
```

from the man page for wait():

> WIFEXITED(status)
>                 returns true if the child terminated normally, that is, by calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main().

What is the right way to make WIFEXITED() return false?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the right way to make WIFEXITED() return false?

Kill the child using a signal. Then `WIFSIGNALED` will be true and `WTERMSIG` will give you the signal.

---

Note you should also check the return code from `wait`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I don't want to use a signal because I'm testing an extreme case when something went terribly wrong in the child and not just in a signal case...

Comment: @DavidDR It's just what `WIFEXITED` means in Unix: this process didn't exit (normally or abnormally): it died as a result of a signal. In other words, if a process ceases to exist either `WIFEXITED` is true or `WIFSIGNALED`.